# Close a program at a set time after opening

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to make a batch file that will close a program at a set time after opening it.  So, for example, if I open my email program, the batch file will be triggered, and after two minutes, my email will automatically close.  If possible, I would also like the command window to open hidden.  I tried working with the Event Logger and the Task Scheduler, but I got nowhere fast.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run Command hidden

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /k dir c:\windows\*.*", 0, false
```

This detects when an app exits. Here when notepad exits it restarts it. You can alter it to process starts, stops, or both. `Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, `Win32_ProcessStartTrace`, and `Win32_ProcessStartStopTrace`.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

This goes through the list of running processes and if Calculator terminates it.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    'msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

To have a script wait. From Help at https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Suspends script execution for a specified length of time, then continues execution.

```
object.Sleep(intTime)
```

**object** 
WScript object.

**intTime** 
Integer value indicating the interval (in milliseconds) you want the script process to be inactive.

So `wscript.sleep 120000` is two minutes

I'll leave you to tie it together.